# Bootstrap 3 Scrollspy remove active state

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have a site using Bootstrap with scrollspy and a fixed header. I have it working fine, but have run into a problem with scrollspy. There are a couple sections on the page that aren't part of the main navigation. When you're in these sections, the most recent 'active' link remains. Easiest to demonstrate the issue in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eric1086/R7S9t/1/

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".main-nav">
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#first">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fourth">Fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fifth">Fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="no-spy">
    Don't spy me!
</section>
<section class="block" id="first">
    First
</section>
etc...
```

Basically I only want the active state to show when a targeted element from the navbar is actually showing. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same happened to me, this is what I did.
I don't know if it's the best way to do it but it works.
Here's the code in your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZGsPm/1/

You add extra list items where your ignored sections go and add them a class ("ignore" in the example) and an id.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".main-nav">
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="ignore"><a href="#no-spy-first"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#first">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fourth">Fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fifth">Fifth</a></li>
    <li class="ignore"><a href="#no-spy-second"></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then you add the corresponding id to those sections so you can reference them from the list item.

```
<section class="no-spy" id="no-spy-first">
    Don't spy me!
</section>

<section class="block" id="first">
    First
</section>
...
<section class="no-spy last" id="no-spy-second">
    Don't spy me!
</section>
```

And finally, in Javascript (after you called the scrollspy function):

```
$('.ignore').css({'visibility':'hidden', 'width':'0%'});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This definitely works - clever workaround. This would be a nice feature to implement in Scrollspy - ideally without the need to add additional list items.

Comment: This works, but I believe the only CSS you need for the `.ignore` class is `display:none;`. That way it works when nav is both full-width and collapsed.