# disable scrollspy on smooth scroll angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use smooth scroll and scrollSpy from angularJS because i have an angular script, so I can't use bootstrap's scrollspy because of hash but that of angularJS especially :
https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/

And I don't know how to disable the scrollspy and the solution `$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active' });` doesn't work because it's not bootstrap.

Thanks.

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915413/bootstrap-3-scrollspy-remove-active-state

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help me :/

Comment: I just want to disable scroll spy when I click on the menu and that the scroll smooth begin. 
When I scroll manually the page I want the menu to react. 
Can I disactivate before the `scrolltop` and reactivate after ?